# How to get Intellij Idea to display compilation warnings?

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-warnings, javac

I'm working with Intellij Idea 10 and Java 6 JDK Update 7. When I run `Build --> Rebuild Project` command, and the (javac) compilation generates warnings, Idea doesn't display *what* those warnings exactly are in the `Messages` view. I just see an "Information: XX warnings" node, but no way to expand it to see the actual warnings. Or I just see a message "Compilation completed successfully with XX warnings" on the status bar. For errors, Idea displays the error information (error message, filename, line number etc.) automatically. How can I get it to work similarly with warnings?

(For the record, I've already tried using additional command line parameters such as `-Xlint`, but it does not make a difference.)

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775315/intellij-show-where-errors-are

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make sure that "**Hide Warnings**" option is **disabled** in the **Messages panel** on the left:

[image: Hide Warnings]

Comment: Has this changed since IDEA 10?
In my 12.1 Ultimate, I see the **Event Log** with 'Compilation completed successfully with 2 warnings'. But no **Messages** visible and I can't see how to open it. (*View > Tool Windows > Messages* is disabled)

Comment: @lian, make some error in the code so that the panel appears.

Comment: Still seems true in 13.1 that you must generate an error to get the messages view so that you can enable display of warnings...

Comment: see here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775315/intellij-show-where-errors-are

Comment: My "messages" view completely disappears and then comes back when I compile, but I still don't see any warnings that are generated.

Comment: FYI there are unchecked conversion warnings that you have to tell javac rather than intellij to show. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857514/why-java-compiler-doesnt-report-unchecked-cast-warnings-for-multi-cast-expressi