# Intellij Idea highlight src with errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm investigating switching from Eclipse Scala IDE to Intellij 15 + Scala plugin.

I can see that compile errors are reported in the Messages tool, but I can't see any highlighting of source files containing errors in the project tree.

Is this feature not available?  If not, how do you cope?  Have I been just spoiled by Eclipse and should learn to 'rough it'?

**Update**
This question is different to [IntelliJ - show where errors are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775315/intellij-show-where-errors-are) because:

- This question is concerned with visual indicators against **files in the folder/file tree view**.
- That question is concerned with indicators **within the files being edited**.  This can be seen in the accepted answer, where the screenshot concerns editor settings for code highlighting.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775315/intellij-show-where-errors-are .

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue with the exact same request when I switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110767 !

After a while you become accustomed to look at the messages window where you get active links which when clicked, directly take you to the error.

Having syntax highlighting in the tree is nice when you refactor and hence tend to break a lot of existing code. At the same time automatic refactoring was (still is?) much better in IntelliJ than it was in Eclipse.