# Android Studio Editor does not underline errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

My Android Studio (2.3.3) Editor does not underline Errors like eclipse. One could easily see all the errors without checking each tag at scrollbar individually for errors.

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: This should resolve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775315/intellij-show-where-errors-are

Answer (score 6):

Disable power saver mode

There is a power saver mode in Android Studio. If accidentally you click on that it will disable code analysis which will reduce the battery consumption and performance will also increase but it will not detect any errors and do auto complete operations.

To disable power saver mode

Go to **File** Menu of Android Studio and uncheck the **Power Saver Mode**

Comment: There is a power saver mode in android studio if accidentally you click on that it will disable code analysis which will reduce the battery consumption and performance will also increase but it will not detect any errors and do auto complete operations.