# How to let AndroidStudio show all compile errors at once?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors

Reluctantly I turned from Eclipse to AndroidStudio for developing apps (only for that). What is really annoying to me is that AndroidStudio does not show all compile errors at once or I haven't found the right option till now.

Given these stupid classes first everything is fine:

A.kt

```
package so

class A(val a: Int) {

    fun add(b: Int): Int {
        return a + b
    }
}
```

B.kt

```
package so

class B {

    fun foo() {
        val a = A(1)
        val c = a.add(2)
    }
}
```

C.kt

```
package so

class C {

    fun bar() {
        val a = A(3)
        val c = a.add(4)
    }
}
```

Now, if I'm in `A` and by mistake remove a letter from method name `add` so its name becomes `ad`. Then, no error is shown in `B` or `C`:

[image]

Neither `Build > Make Project` nor `Build > Rebuild Project` mark the errorneous classes though they are listed in the compile log:

[image]

Only if opening `B` or `C` in the editor the buggy class are underlined in red.

[image]

Sometimes I detect syntax errors a long while after changing some code at another place.

Is there any solution for this, any option I have overseen?

Comment: I've seen same things, but i guess you can't actually change it. Reason is problems of IDE even IntelliJ IDEA have same problems.

Comment: @Raguel Really? Such an issue in a commercial product? My hope was someone says _hey, you forgot to enable this or that_.

Comment: This is truly annoying. In case of rebasing and having errors, I compare with the branch I am rebeasing with and go through each file to see if there are any problems. Otherwise, one build only shows a problem in one-two classes.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this is what solved the issue for me. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556424/1080585

Answer (score 3):

That's a known issue. Some versions of Kotlin hide build errors in some releases of Android Studio. Thus, **Android Studio** frustratingly doesn't display them in the `Messages` tab. But you can still find all the errors – you have to open the `Gradle Console` to get to them.

Hope this will be fixed in a future releases of AS.