# Warnings in IntelliJ IDEA v12

Tags: intellij-idea

The answer given for [How to get Intellij Idea to display compilation warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745415/how-to-get-intellij-idea-to-display-compilation-warnings) no longer applies from version 12. There is no longer a messages panel, as far as I can see.

How can I see a full list of all warnings in the project in version 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option and the `Messages` panel is on the same place as before in IDEA 12.0.3:

[image: panel]

If you don't see it, it means that your project has no errors. Make any error and the panel will appear. Verify that `Hide warnings` is not enabled. Fix the error, Make the project again, you should see only warnings:

[image: warnings]

Note that Make is incremental, if there were no changes, it will not compile and report any old warnings, so you may need to **Rebuild** to see all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are correct. My question was misguided. I'm looking for a place where the IDE would list all of the inspection warnings, not the compiler warnings.

Comment: `Analyze` | `Inspect Code`.