# Intellij show warnings as errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A feature I like in eclipse the most is that it easily shows me all my errors and warnings in the code (in a list)

Also - by each file there is a mark whether the file has warnings/errors

In Intellij I found it rather challenging...
So for all the Intellij experts out there -

1. Is there a way so show warnings in a list (I saw something similar in the messages toolbar but it dissapears when there are no compilation errors)
2. How can I see if a file has warnings without looking into it's contents?

Thanks!

Comment: this is the only area where intellij is not as good as eclipse, imho.  I still prefer intellij, as its just this one feature that is a bit lame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also I like error/warning list that appears when trying to commit file into Subversion. If any errors or warnings present in file, IDEA shows popup window with **Review** button. This button opens **Message** sub-window with very handy and good-looking errors/warnings list.
P.S. Also may be helpful **Build** -> **Rebuild Project**
P.S.2. Also see about displaying warnings here: [Warnings in IntelliJ IDEA v12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804556/warnings-in-intellij-idea-v12?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're looking for is "Inspect Code" under the "Analyze" menu. It allows you to specify which inspections you want to run (called an Inspection Profile) and on what set of files, and puts them all in a window to let you look through them and resolve them.

See [Code Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-inspection.html) in the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks Peter!
I've already explored this option.
This doesn't mark my files as "with warning"...

Answer (score 0):

If you do build->rebuild project in IntelliJ, the messages tab (usually at the bottom) should show all the warnings. They should not disappear anywhere even after compiler has finished. If they do, check you have not enabled the "hide warnings" icon on the messages tab.

I guess the difference with Eclipse is due to Eclipse always running the background compiler and also collecting the warnings. IntelliJ runs its own parser and highlights errors in the source tree, haven't really needed the warnings to be displayed always so not sure how to do that.