# why java compiler doesn't report unchecked cast warnings for multi-cast expression in Intellij?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, java-8

Why the code below didn't report unchecked warnings by Intellij IDEA with `jdk 1.8.0_121` since   `Supplier<R> & Serializable` is the supertype of `T`?

```
<T extends Supplier<Integer> & Serializable> T createdBy(AtomicInteger counter) {
    //      v--- if I removed the first cast expression, I can't compile it
    return (T) (Supplier<Integer> & Serializable) counter::incrementAndGet;
    //           ^--- it should be reports unchecked warnings, but it doesn't

}
```

And the following code has reported unchecked cast warnings:

```
<T, R extends T> R apply(T value) {
    return (R) value;
    //      ^--- unchecked cast 
}
```

Why this question occurs, the interested thing occurs during I write the code at below for chaining a type with multi-supertypes:

```
AtomicInteger counter  = new AtomicInteger(0);
Supplier<Integer>  serialized = serialized(createdBy(counter));

assert serialized.get() == 1; // ok
assert counter.get() == 0 ; // ok

<T extends Serializable> T serialized(T value) {
    return deserialize(serialize(value));
}
```

I have searched through the JLS, but I can't find out the exactly favorable evidence. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Because it doesn't think the casts are unchecked. If you think otherwise please state why, with supporting evidence such as code, i.e. the relevant declarations. There's not enough here to go on.

Comment: This code is pretty strange, I don't see why there's a method reference returned here.

Comment: @RC. just an coped example. which can be for chaining purpose.

Comment: @EJP sir, you can see another method `apply` in my edited answer, that has reported unchecked cast warnings.

Comment: But what I cannot see is the definition of `get()`, which is the only thing that *is* relevant.

Comment: @EJP I'm very sorry, sir. maybe the `get()` confused you. I have updated my answer now. please see it again. Indeed, I used a generic return type for bind multi-supertypes. then I'm happy to chaining it . but it doesn't report any unchecked cast warnings.

Comment: And what I cannot see now is the definition of `incrementAndGet()`. You're wasting time.

Comment: @EJP I'm sorry I wasted your time. the intention is that I want to know why an `unchecked cast` warnings is not reported by compiler.

Comment: Repeating your question doesn't answer my question. You are casting a method whose definition you have not provided. It is impossible to answer your question until you do so. I asked for this over an hour ago. Merely changing the method name and reiterating your original question is not sufficient.

Comment: @EJP the `incrementAndGet` method is defined by `AtomicInteger`, and the method signature was changed. I'm sorry I'm not good at english. maybe my bad english confused you. but my intention is  clearly. I just want to know why, sir? the problem comes from when I write some tests to verify the function and the used variables are all serialized in apache spark.

Comment: @holi-java about this: `(T) (Supplier<Integer> & Serializable) counter::incrementAndGet;` what compiler are you using? I've tried `javac 8 build 131`; `javac 9 build 175`; and latest eclipse compiler and each of them post a warning

Comment: @Eugene first, thank you for the testing. I never test it in command way. I'm using the Intellij IDEA with `jdk 1.8.0_121` didn't report any unchecked cast warnings. and I find my local jdk also reported the unchecked cast warnings.  why?

Comment: @holi-java you mean `javac` reported the warning and intellij did not?

Comment: @Eugene yes, sir. :). I have tested it just now. I'm sure I used the same jdk. and the `-Xlint` option also enabled in intellij, but it didn't report any warnings.

Comment: @holi-java sounds like IDEA bug to me - I don't use it so can't really tell you...

Comment: @Eugene hi, sir. are you using eclipse? did it report unchecked cast warnings?

Comment: @holi-java yes - eclipse does report the warning

Comment: @Eugene the IDEA confused me for this for a while. :), thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA for the java compiler to report unchecked warnings you need to add `-Xlint:unchecked` option to the Java Compiler | Additional Command line parameters:

[image: unchecked]

If you try to compile it using the command line `javac`, it will also not report you the warning itself, but will tell how to enable unchecked warnings:

```
Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

The same message is displayed by IntelliJ IDEA if this option is not specified:

[image: unchecked]

After you add `-Xlint:unchecked` option, the output would change to:

```
Information:javac 1.8.0_121 was used to compile java sources
Information:01.07.2017 16:07 - Compilation completed successfully with 1 warning in 2s 553ms
D:\work\attaches\unchecked\src\Main.java
    Warning:Warning:line (9)java: unchecked cast
  required: T
  found:    java.lang.Object&java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.Integer>&java.io.Serializable
```

As you can see, IntelliJ IDEA behaves exactly the same as the command line `javac`.